# Passing union type annotation into knex returns any type

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, postgresql, knex.js

Knex version: 2.5.1
Database + version: postgres15

1. If I have a union typescript definition and pass it into the knex as a type annotation it returns the type any. If I use type assertion `as UserRecord` at the end I do get the UserRecord type. From what I understand I should use type annotation  and pass `UserRecord` into knex like `knex<UserRecord>('users')...`. I understand that if a provider is `GOOGLE` for example 1password1 will be `null` in the database and technically should be `null` in the `const user` but shoulden't the example below return `UserRecord` and not `any`?

```js
export type UserRecord = {
    id: string
    name: string
    email: string
    active: boolean
    avatar: string | null
} & (
    | {
          provider: 'GITLAB' | 'GITHUB' | 'GOOGLE'
          providerId: string
      }
    | {
          provider: 'EMAIL'
          password: string
      }
)

// returns type any
const user = await knex<UserRecord>('users').select('id', 'name', 'provider', 'email', 'active', 'avatar', 'password').where('email', req.body.email).first()
if (!user) {
    return res.status(400).json({ success: false, message: 'USER_NOT_FOUND' })
}
```

Comment: I tried the recommended way [documented here](https://knexjs.org/guide/#typescript) which consists in augmenting the `Tables` interface but got the same result: https://tsplay.dev/mpQnbW

Answer (score 0):

As documented here: https://knexjs.org/guide/#typescript

> However it is to be noted that TypeScript support is currently best-effort. Knex has a very flexible API and not all usage patterns can be type-checked and in most such cases we err on the side of flexibility. In particular, lack of type errors doesn't currently guarantee that the generated queries will be correct and therefore writing tests for them is recommended even if you are using TypeScript.

The case when you want to select a field that does not necessarily exist in the type definition appears not to be supported as it falls back to `any`. I guess you have no other choice than casting the type yourself.